# How to bind a validated entry value to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Based on a answer from an earlier stackoverflow I tried to bind an entry (via entry.get) to a variable. Initially it seemed to work as I can indeed change the value as indicated by a print call in the get_value method. However at the end the variable has not been changed, as is shown by pressing check button. I hope somebody can show what I'm doing wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Label(master, text ='Fox number').grid(row=0,column=0)
        tk.Label(master, text ='Hare number').grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.fox_entry=tk.Entry(master,width=5, validate="key")
        self.fox_entry['validatecommand'] =\
            self.fox_entry.register(self.is_okay),'%P'
        self.hare_entry=tk.Entry(master, width=5, validate="key")
        self.hare_entry['validatecommand'] =\
            self.hare_entry.register(self.is_okay),'%P'
        self.fox_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.hare_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def is_okay(self, P):
        try:
            if P == '' or int(P) >= 0:
                return True            
        except:
            return False

class Ecosystem():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foxnumber = 100
        self.harenumber = 10
        self.inputvalue = None

    def animal_entries(self):        
        def input_user(entry):
            def get_value(event):
                self.inputvalue = entry.get()
                print(self.inputvalue)
                return self.inputvalue
            entry.bind('<Return>', get_value)
            return self.inputvalue

        my_win.fox_entry.insert(0,self.foxnumber)
        my_win.hare_entry.insert(0,self.harenumber)
        self.inputvalue = self.foxnumber
        self.foxnumber = input_user(my_win.fox_entry)
        self.inputvalue = self.harenumber
        self.harenumber = input_user(my_win.hare_entry)

    def write(self):
        print('hares: ', self.harenumber, 'foxes: ',self.foxnumber)       

master = tk.Tk()
my_win = Window()
my_ecosystem = Ecosystem()
my_ecosystem.animal_entries()
tk.Button(master, text = 'check',command=my_ecosystem.write).grid(row=2, column=0)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I tried to bind an entry (via entry.get) to a variable."_ - `.get()` doesn't bind an entry to a a variable, it simply copies the value in the widget to a variable.

Comment: Hi Bryan, that is what meant to say. I want to change the values of self.foxnumber en self .harenumber.  But in the end the values of both variables do not change. In the simple code I added to my question, they remain 100 and 10.